# ContinueWhenAll not working with Async Events

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous

I have adapted some code that executes events asynchronously from v2.0 async structures to the TPL.  It all seems to work well enough, but I've one oddity that I can't figure out.

This is the class that handles firing events asynchronously:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class Event
    {    
        delegate void AsyncFire(Delegate fn, object[] args);

        private static async Task UnsafeFireAsync(Delegate fn, params object[] args)
        {
            if (fn == null)
                return;

            Delegate[] callList = fn.GetInvocationList();
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
            AsyncFire asyncFire = InvokeDelegate;

            foreach (Delegate sink in callList)
            {                
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
                asyncFire.BeginInvoke(sink, args, AsyncCallback, tcs);
                taskList.Add(tcs.Task);
            }

            await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), null);
        }

        static void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            AsyncFire asyncFire = InvokeDelegate;
            var tcs = (TaskCompletionSource<object>)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                asyncFire.EndInvoke(ar);
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e);
            }

        }

        static void InvokeDelegate(Delegate fn, object[] args)
        {
            fn.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }

        public static async Task FireAsync(EventHandler fn, object sender)
        {
            await UnsafeFireAsync(fn, sender, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        public static async Task FireAsync<T>(EventHandler<T> fn, object sender, T e) where T : EventArgs
        {
            await UnsafeFireAsync(fn, sender, e);
        }   
    }
}
```

I then have a class that provides some events and a couple of subs to call them:

```
namespace AsyncEventTest
{
    class AsyncEvents
    {
        public event EventHandler Event1;
        public event EventHandler Event2;
        public event EventHandler Event3;
        public event EventHandler Event4;
        public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> Event5;

        public void DoProcess()
        {
            Event1(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Event2(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Event3(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Event4(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Event5(this, new StringEventArgs("Event 5 parameter"));
        }

        public async Task DoProcessPartialAsync()
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(DoProcess);
        }

        public async Task DoProcessFullAsync()
        {
            Task[] taskList = new Task[5];
            taskList[0] = Event.FireAsync(Event1, this);
            taskList[1] = Event.FireAsync(Event2, this);
            taskList[2] = Event.FireAsync(Event3, this);
            taskList[3] = Event.FireAsync(Event4, this);
            taskList[4] = Event.FireAsync(Event5, this, new StringEventArgs("Event 5 parameter"));

            await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a from that calls the AsyncEvents class and consumes its events:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    AsyncEvents events = new AsyncEvents();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        events.Event1 += events_Event1;
        events.Event2 += events_Event2;
        events.Event3 += events_Event3;
        events.Event4 += events_Event4;
        events.Event5 += events_Event5;
    }

    void events_Event5(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        AddToEventList("Event 5 Message: " + e.Message);
    }

    void events_Event4(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        AddToEventList("Event 4 Done");
    }

    void events_Event3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        AddToEventList("Event 3 Done");
    }

    void events_Event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        AddToEventList("Event 2 Done");
    }

    void events_Event1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        AddToEventList("Event 1 Done");
    }

    private void FireAsyncBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AsyncOutputList.Items.Clear();            
        events.DoProcessPartialAsync().ContinueWith(t => AddToEventList("DoProcess call done"));
        AddToEventList("DoProcess call returned");
    }        

    private void FireFullAsyncBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AsyncOutputList.Items.Clear();
        events.DoProcessFullAsync().ContinueWith(t => AddToEventList("DoProcess call done"));
        AddToEventList("DoProcess call returned");
    }

    private void AddToEventList(string msg)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke((Action<string>)AddToEventList, msg);
            return;
        }

        AsyncOutputList.Items.Add(msg);
    }
}
```

The partial async call runs as expected:

[image: Partial Async Run]

The fully async call though executes the ContinueWith before the events have finished executing:

[image: Fully Async Run]

My question is, why?  I can't see why the "DoProcess Done" line is being output early.

Comment: It's not a very good code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. So I haven't bothered to try to reproduce the problem. But I do notice that you're passing `null` as the `continuationAction` parameter for `ContinueWhenAll()`, which would throw an exception. You're probably just not noticing the exception because you don't have any try/catch yourself and the Forms event dispatching is swallowing it. You should just use `WhenAll()` if you don't have any actual continuation to perform (and when you do, for that matter, since you can just write the continuation after with `await`).

Comment: Not the point of the question, but you can replace the entire invocation logic with `Task.Run(() => asyncFire(sink, args))`.

Comment: I don't understand your criticism Peter.  The code I provided is minimal, complete and verifiable.

Comment: Also, I don't have a WhenAll method available.  I think that was added in .Net 4.5; I'm using v4.0.

Comment: As for Exception handling, why do you think the Forms event dispatching is swallowing exceptions?  The code that fires the event using the old Begin/End async style and, as I understand it, if an exception is thrown from the event handler or the InvokeDelegate method then it should be re-raised when the EndInvoke method is called.  This is being caught and set in the TaskCompletionSource which should then cause an AggregateException to be raised from the ContinueWhenAll call.

Comment: I also don't see why it would cause the Continuation to run early as it should not attempt to call the null Continuation until of the tasks in the array have completed. Still, I added in a completion function instead of null and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks usr.  Based on your suggestion I've simplified it further to: Task.Factory.StartNew(() => sink.DynamicInvoke(args))

Comment: Peter, I take it back.  I only changed one of the ContinueWhenAll calls.  Setting a continuation method on both resolved the issue.  I'm still unsure why the exception was being swallowed though.